# The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem

Tags: apt, samba, compiling

I'm trying to install Samba 4.0.9 on one server but I keep getting this error everytime. I have tried everything from `apt-get -f install` to editing `/var/lib/dpkg/status` `Package: Samba4 Install ok installed`

This is the error I get:

```
[ 866/3792] Compiling source4/dsdb/common/util.c
[ 867/3792] Compiling source4/dsdb/common/util_groups.c
In file included from ../lib/replace/system/time.h:30:0,
                 from ../source4/include/includes.h:33,
                 from ../source4/dsdb/common/util_groups.c:22:
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/time.h:61:3: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem.
Waf: Leaving directory `/samba/bin'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cc util_groups.c -> util_groups_6.o}
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

If more information is needed I will provide it for you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "so it is likely a hardware or OS problem," if true, suggests that this may not be a bug in the sense we use the term here. Therefore, before closing this, I recommend we include some explanation for why this is a bug after all. (I cannot think of such an explanation, but perhaps others will be able to.)

Comment: Have you booted into grub and run memtest?

Comment: How are you trying to install Samba 4? Your mention of package management tools and files suggests through the package manager, but the code listing suggests from source.

Answer (score 3):

When debian gcc encounters an internal error it tries to run the code through the compilation core again. If it gets the same results every time it assumes it really is a bug in the compiler core. If it doesn't then you get the "The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem." message.

This could be caused by a bug in the compiler core that is sensitive to some external factor, a bug in the kernel or dodgy hardware.

Answer (score 3):

You may also see this message if you are running a build system that executes some build steps in parallel on a multi-core machine and one of those steps requires an output from the other, but the build system doesn't know it.

For example:

- step1: generate header file that gets used by step 2
- step2: run gcc to compile a .c file that includes the header from from step 1.

If the build system doesn't know that step2 depends on the output of step1, then it may try to take advantage of the fact that it has multiple CPU cores available to it and run both steps at the same time.  In this case, step2 will fail because the header file it needs hasn't been generated yet.  On failure, gcc retries the compilation, but by this point, step1 has completed and the header file is available.  So, the second try succeeds and gcc assumes that the inconsistent results mean that the OS or the hardware is failing in some way, even though they are functioning perfectly.

This is a good example of a multi-threaded race condition, which can be a highly unpredictable thing when found in more complex scenarios (such as the build system of a large project like Samba).

I experienced this personally using the ninja build system on another project.

The way to fix it is to make sure that your build scripts make the build system aware of the dependency between steps.

Comment: A race condition in the dependency tree alone shouldn't cause segfaults in the compiler.

Comment: Agreed.  It should not.

Comment: But keep in mind that the compiler uses files, and it may be possible that two invocations of the compiler may be using the same files at the same time, thereby stepping on each other's toes.  In a program as complex as a compiler, I think they should be forgiven for missing such an obscure, unpredictable corner case as this.  And even in this case, it doesn't just crash.  It catches the segfault and tries to provide some useful info.